# Visualforce Component <inputText> not setting value for Map of a wrapper class onChange event

Tags: visualforce, map, set

I have a wrapper class within my component controller

```
public class WrapperClass{

    public Decimal  base        { get; set; }
    public Decimal  goal        { get; set; }
    public String   suffix      { get; set; }
    ...

    public Goal(String suffix, Decimal base, Decimal goal){
        this.suffix = suffix;
        this.base = base;
        this.goal = goal;
    }
}
```

This is then constructed into a map that is indexed by month like so:

`public Map<String,WrapperClass> wrapperItems{ get; set; }`

I also have a wrapper class for `Month` and have a list of those that I `<apex:repeat>` through in my component like so:

**Component:**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!months}" var="month">

<apex:inputText id="myId" value="{!wrapperItems[month.Name].goal}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!modifyItem}" rerender="currentSection" status="mypoller">
        <!-- I've attempted passing parameters to get what I need but with no luck -->
        <apex:param name="month" value="{!month.name}"></apex:param>
        <apex:param name="suffix" value="{!wrapperItems[month.Name].suffix}"></apex:param>
    </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:inputText>

</apex:repeat>
```

*NOTE: I'm using actionSupport to do an `onChange` event, not sure if that would have any effect here, and not sure of another option to get desired interaction*

**Controller:**

```
public PageReference modifyItem(){
    String month = String.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('month'));
    System.debug('::ITEM:: '+wrapperItems.get(month));
}
```

I've got getters/setters setup in my wrapper class and for the `wrapperItems` map, which I found was a common issue for other users. Not sure what else I'm missing here so really appreciate any help that can be offered.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just add an instance of `WrapperClass` as a property on `Month`? Just don't want to inject that dependency?

Comment: Never really thought to... They are two separate objects it would seem odd to me to put them together.

Comment: All I can see is the data structure, so it made me curious. Then you could bind directly (e.g. `value="{!month.wrapperInstance.goal}"`). You could also make a separate `ComboWrapper` that has both so it's more natural.

Comment: Why don't you try with `apex:param assignTo="{!wrapper.variable}"` for each row ?

Comment: Instead of `apex:actionsupport`, you should use on-change event and call action function while passing necessary parameters. Then you may get binded values also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the hint from [@Ankuli](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5634/ankuli) in the comments I went ahead with the `<apex:actionfunction>` approach. This solved part of my problem by at least allowing me to send parameters of my newly input data, but I still had an issue with "setting" the values... or so I thought.

In case you don't realize this already, [component constructors happen PRIOR to GETTERS/SETTERS being established](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102119/visualforce-component-getter-setters-from-a-base-class), so if your constructor relies on any of these, good luck! At least with VF pages when you have an issue in the context of the constructor *(for example DML and Platform Cache attempts)*, [you can use the `action="{!init}"` attribute/approach](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000H6PM).

With these things to consider, basically this leaves you with hooking into a setter so that you can execute an "init" method to build out what you need. For example:

```
public String someVar { get; 
    set{
        init();
    } 
}
```

Followed by your `init()`, keep in mind that on pageReferences and anything else that hits your setters, this will fire again unless you prevent it with some come counter/boolean variable:

```
void init(){
    this.var1 = '';
    this.var2 = (var2==NULL) ? '1' : var2;
}
```

Also here is a quick summary of my use of the `actionFunction` implementation:

**Repeat Fields:**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myList}" var="i">
    <apex:outputPanel id="rowOfMyList" styleClass="row field-row" layout="block">
        <apex:inputText id="inputId" value="{!i.obj.value}" html-data-index="{!i.obj.index}" html-data-render="{!$Component.rowOfMyList}" onChange="updateField(this)"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```

**JS Script:**

```
function updateField(row) {
    myActionFunction(row.getAttribute('data-index'), row.value, row.getAttribute('data-render'));
}
```

**Action Function:**

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!pageRefMethod}" name="myActionFunction" rerender="{!renderRow}" >
    <apex:param name="index" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="goal" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="render" assignTo="{!renderRow}" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't put all this in a comment and I don't have the time/energy to research right now, so hopefully I don't get negged for this answer. Just want to try to explain what I'm getting at.

It looks like you have a one to one relationship in your data structure. For 
each `Month`, there is a corresponding `Goal` wrapper, and vice versa. Try creating some sort of combined wrapper such as `MonthlyGoal`:

```
public class MonthlyGoal
{
    public Month month { get; private set; }
    public Goal goal { get; private set; }
}
```

Then, you can just repeat through a `List<MonthlyGoal>` and bind directly, instead of trying to set a map element. I'm not sure if the latter is possible as I've never tried it.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!monthlyGoals}" var="monthlyGoal">
    <apex:outputText value="{!monthlyGoal.month.Name}" />
    <apex:inputText value="{!monthlyGoal.goal.goal}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I appreciate this tip for how much cleaner my code looks and works, but I'm still not getting a new value. Markup looks like this: `<apex:inputText value="{!i.goal.value}">` Then within pagereference method I have this debug `System.debug('m.month.name+': '+m.goal.value);` but still get original `set` value

Comment: Using `<apex:actionfunction>` I was finally able to get the new value passed through a parameter but I can't manually set it for some reason it doesn't work. I passed the index and new value from the action function and I attempt to set with this `monthlyGoals[index].goal.setGoal(goal)` and debug of `setGoal()` shows the new value but when the `monthlyGoals` List is not modified. I guess I figured it would be "pass-by" referenced...